# How to render a .vue file?

Tags: vue.js, nginx, webpack

I have a VPS server running with nginx on which my vuejs project is located.
When I type the domain name in my search bar I would like my default .vue page to be displayed but .vue files aren't supposed to be for direct accessing in the browser.

From what I understand I need to use Webpack and build but I don't know how to do that on my vps..

So how can I use it ?

Comment: You can either install Node on VPS and proceed exactly the way you'd build an app on PC. Or you can deploy a prebuilt app, especially if VPS is weak

Comment: Now I've got a directory called dist created and "ready to be deployed" what do I do with this ? There is no .html files

Comment: Who knows? It's unknown what is your setup and why there are no .html. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If it's not your own project, you could ask for a clarification on deploy from a dev.

Comment: You need to config nginx to route traffics to the built distribution files. You can search for some examples, like https://www.appsyoda.com/blog/deploying-vuejs-app-using-nginx/

Just an additional information. If you are deploying a Vue SPA, I would suggest you to serve through file bucket like S3, or use static hosting services like Cloudflare Pages and Firebase Hosting. Which is cheaper than using a VPS.

Comment: Netlify and Vercel are also really good alternatives. Even tho, I still don't understand why you would want an `.html` in your filename. Vue's extensions properly highlight that in VScode/others IDEs.